# MongoDB Java | Update record from null to String

Tags: java, mongodb, nosql, mongodb-query

I have a record in my document which is null (has the datatype null) and I want to change that record to String and assign a value to it.

```
BasicDBObject newDocument = new BasicDBObject();
newDocument.append("$set", new BasicDBObject().append("nickname", commandRaw[3]));
DBObject searchQuery = new BasicDBObject("_id", user._id); 
collection.update(searchQuery, newDocument);
```

commandRaw[3] is the String value which should be updating the null record. But it doesn't seem to work that way.

Comment: what is the issue you are facing and where?

Comment: The record I am trying to update has the datatype of null. When I try to update the record to a string, it doesn't change, it's still null. And the above code works fine, when the record is not null, but an empty String for example.

Comment: Not sure, I executed your code and it worked fine: Before Update - { "_id" : { "$oid" : "5ac18e3540daee0427f03461"} , "nickname" :  null } After Update -
{ "_id" : { "$oid" : "5ac18e3540daee0427f03461"} , "nickname" : "aman"}

Comment: Just to be extra sure, can you share what is the value of commandRaw[3] . May be you can try toString or new String(commandRaw[3]) if that helps.

Comment: Thanks for your help! Turns out the problem was something with the searchQuery, when I used something else than the _id it worked.

Comment: Great! Nice to know that :)